# Unable to run Sails after npm install

Tags: npm, sails.js

I am trying to set up a new sails application but when I try to install sails with npm, it says I need to fund packages and gives me the error "command not found: sails." The thing is in my node_modules folder, I can see the sails folder but I cannot use it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have tried to install/update all the listed packages but it continues to say that I need to fund the packages

[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsdgV.png)